# How are the retarded and advanced Lienard-Wiechert EM potentials interpreted?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, classical-field-theory

Before QFT was developed in its current form, the Lienard-Wiechert EM potentials were mathematically interpreted as diverging/converging from/upon an electric charge q in the retarded and advanced cases respectively. How has this picture changed today; given that the electron is considered to be an excitation of an electron field, a photon an excitation of the electromagnetic field?

In particular, are the electric charges still considered sources/sinks of the retarded/advanced LW potentials in today's models of CED?